# Why Collections.sort() doesn't work in Eclipse

Tags: java

`public interface Comparable <T>{
    public int CompareTo (T other);
}`

```
public class CalendarDate implements Comparable<CalendarDate>{
private int month;
private int day;

public CalendarDate( int month, int day) {
    this.month = month;
    this.day = day;
}

public int CompareTo(CalendarDate other) {
    if (month != other.month) {
        return month - other.month;
    }
    else {
        return day - other.day;
    }
}

public int getMonth(){
    return month;
}
public int getDay() {
    return day;
}
public String toString() {
    return month + "/" + day;
}
```

}

```
import java.util.*;
public class CalendarDateTest {
    public static void main (String []args) {
        ArrayList <CalendarDate> dates = new ArrayList<CalendarDate>();
        dates.add(new CalendarDate(2,22));
        dates.add(new CalendarDate(10,30));
        dates.add(new CalendarDate(4, 13));
        dates.add(new CalendarDate(3,16));
        dates.add(new CalendarDate(4,28));
        System.out.println("birthdays = " + dates);
        Collections.sort(dates);
        System.out.println("birthdays = " + dates);

    }
}
```

I used an exact example from my textbook, but the Collections.sort() just ain't working somehow, please help.
It says:

Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
    The method sort(List) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList)

```
at CalendarDateTest.main(CalendarDateTest.java:11)
```

Comment: That's just a typo, most likely: `public int CompareTo(...)`  should be `public int compareTo(...)` with a small / non-capital / lower `c`. Eclipse doesn't consider your implementation as overriding `compareTo` because the method names are not equal. This method must be implemented by a `Comparable` and `Collections.sort()` needs valid `Comparable`s in the collection.

Comment: At first, it's lower c which doesn't work and I saw some compare function online that made me somehow tried. But that's not the problem cuz it's still not working.  
  Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<CalendarDate>)

 at CalendarDateTest.main(CalendarDateTest.java:11)

Answer (score -1):

It works in my environment, the result is below. I am using JDK8, the only problem in your paste code is the CompareTo function should be compareTo, C should be lowercase. Don't define your own Comparable interface.

birthdays = [2/22, 10/30, 4/13, 3/16, 4/28]
birthdays = [2/22, 3/16, 4/13, 4/28, 10/30]

[And your question is the same as this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35688550/error-message-the-method-sortlistt-in-the-type-collections-is-not-applicabl)

Comment: I tried the lower case, but it just not work somehow.                                                
     Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
 The method sort(List<T>) in the type Collections is not applicable for the arguments (ArrayList<CalendarDate>)

 at CalendarDateTest.main(CalendarDateTest.java:11)